# AWS Cognito app client setup for a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am working on integrating Cognito with the website my team is building for user authentication. I am having troubles with regard to number of ***app client*** that I should setup. In the AWS's official documentation, it says something like this:

> You can create multiple apps for a user pool. Generally an app corresponds to the platform of an app. For example, you might create an app for a server-side application and a different Android app. Each app has its own app client ID.

So normally, lets say for a full stack application, do we need to set up two app clients, one for frontend and one for backend? or it is fine just creating one app client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create 2 app client values to require a user to authenticate to access your web site using a login such as this one:

[image]

You only need one App client id value to secure a web app (the note above is describing a web app and a separate mobile app).

To see an example of securing a web site (this example demonstrates how to secure a Spring boot Web app using the OAuth2  identity provider), see this:

[Using Amazon Cognito to require a user to log into a web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_amazon_cognito_app)

Comment: you are beautiful man! holy really appreciated it